# How to push on the production server only folder prepared for production?

Tags: git, deployment, push, gruntjs

I have the project under git version control. My file structure like the following:

```
.git
build
server
  models
  controllers
  views
site
  css
  js
  img
.gitignore
```

In the 'server' and 'site' folders resides source code that unprepared for production.  I use grunt for preparing js css for production (concat and min) which put  prepared files for production in the 'build' folder, so after grunt it will look like this:

```
build
  server
    models
    controllers
    views
  site
    css  // min
    js   // min
    img  // sprites
```

After that I do 'git commit' and 'git push' to the remote production server. But together with my build folder git push my source code ('server' and 'site' folders which is outside build folder) .That is correct because git versioned all files under application folder. But I need to exclude from pushing these folders for pushing to the server.

How can I do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have a branch which will manage release. Let's say you have a branch named `production` with it's own `.gitignore` file, that way you will push only what you need.

The way I did this

```
mkdir project
cd project
git init
vi .gitigore      # type something and save
git commit -a -m "first commit"
git checkout -b release
vi .gitignore
change content of file
git commit -a -m "update for release"
```

and that's it:-)

Comment: In the same way like every other file:-)

Comment: I just tried on my PC, you can have different .gitignore in different branchces

Comment: No, branchces, I didn't mention folders anywhere